# Parsing AnnotatedString

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

If I want to parse an annotated string, the methods `trim` and `replace` only return a `CharSequence`.

```
val text = buildAnnotatedString {
    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontSize = 30.sp)) {
        append("   How")
    }
    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Red)) {
        append("\n\n")
        append("are you?   ")
    }
}

@Composable
fun Test() = Column {
    Text(text)
    Text(
        AnnotatedString(
            text = text.text.replace(Regex("(\n)+"), " "),
            spanStyles = text.spanStyles,
            paragraphStyles = text.paragraphStyles
        )
    )
    // Text(text.trim().toString())
}
```

If the parsed text is of a different length, it messes with the styles.

```
Process: com.uzential.speedreadingendless, PID: 12758
                 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (6 ... 19) ends beyond length 18
                    at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.checkRange(SpannableStringInternal.java:493)
                    at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan(SpannableStringInternal.java:199)
                    at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan(SpannableStringInternal.java:186)
                    at android.text.SpannableString.setSpan(SpannableString.java:60)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.extensions.SpannableExtensions_androidKt.setSpan(SpannableExtensions.android.kt:81)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.extensions.SpannableExtensions_androidKt.setColor-RPmYEkk(SpannableExtensions.android.kt:522)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.AndroidAccessibilitySpannableString_androidKt.setSpanStyle(AndroidAccessibilitySpannableString.android.kt:95)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.AndroidAccessibilitySpannableString_androidKt.toAccessibilitySpannableString(AndroidAccessibilitySpannableString.android.kt:63)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.getInfoText(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:1433)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.isScreenReaderFocusable(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:768)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.geometryDepthFirstSearch(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:700)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.geometryDepthFirstSearch(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:713)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.subtreeSortedByGeometryGrouping(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:735)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.setTraversalValues(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:750)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.getCurrentSemanticsNodes$ui_release(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:346)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.createEvent$ui_release(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:1585)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendEventForVirtualView(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:1527)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendEventForVirtualView$default(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:1517)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendSubtreeChangeAccessibilityEvents(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:2344)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.boundsUpdatesEventLoop(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:2215)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.boundsUpdatesEventLoop(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1270)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$1.invokeSuspend(Wrapper.android.kt:128)
                    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
15:57:36.314  E     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
                    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@4674928, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@5348641, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@f8b27e6, AndroidUiDispatcher@64c4127]
```

For trimming, I use the `subSequence` method and a while loop.

```
while (text[end] == ' ' || text[end] == '\n') {
    end--
}
text.subSequence(start, end + 1)
```

Is there a way to parse an annotated string with any regex while retaining the styles?